# Dynamic Dropdown Second list not populating

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a dynamic dropdown list where cities populate according to state chosen from a MYSQL Database.

First dropdown populates fine from the database, giving both state name and state_id, when I test for it.

Second dropdown doesn't populate. I think this is because of a problem sending and receiving from the fetch.php file I'm working with.

I think the Ajax is correct. Fetch.php is right beside index.php in my file structure so it should be able to locate it.

Have tried adjusting fetch.php so it doesn't have to connect to db and will just echo a simple option with text, but this will still not update in the city dropdown. New to this so any help would be much appreciated.

HTML Code in Index.php:

```
 <?php require_once('../private/initialize.php'); ?>
 <?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/header.php'); //SHARED_PATH located in initialize.php ?>

        <div id="main-container">
            <form action="" id="cost_form" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">     
                <div id="select-container">
                        <fieldset class="fieldset">
                            <div class="custom-select" >
                              <select id="state"  name="state" class = "form-control" onchange="get_cities(this.value);" >
                                  <option value="" >Select State</option>
                                  <?php $state_set = find_all_states();
                                  while ($state = mysqli_fetch_assoc($state_set)) {
                                      echo '<option value="'.h($state["state_id"]).'">'.$state["state_name"].'</option>';}
                                  ?>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-select" >
                              <select id="city" name="city" class="form-control">
                                  <option value="1">Select City</option>
                              </select> 
                            </div>  

                            <div id="total_price"></div>

                        </fieldset>
                </div>
            </form>             
        </div>

 <?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/footer.php'); //SHARED_PATH located in initialize.php ?> 

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function get_cities(val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "fetch.php",
data:'state_id='+val,

success: function(data){
 $("#city").html(data);
 }
 });
 }
 </script>
```

Fetch.php Code:

```
<?php require_once('../private/initialize.php'); ?>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['state_id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['state_id'];

        $city_set = find_city_by_id($id);
        while ($city = mysqli_fetch_assoc($city_set)) {
          echo '<option value="'.h($city["city_multiplier"]).'">'.$city["city_name"].'</option>';}
    }

    ?>
```

Query Functions, accessed through Initialize.php:

```
   <?php 

    function find_all_states() {
    global $db;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM states ";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    confirm_result_set($result);
    return $result;
}

function find_city_by_id($id) {
    global $db;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE state_id ='".$id."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    confirm_result_set($result);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Database, accessed through Initialize.php:

```
<?php 

    require_once ('db_credentials.php');

    function db_connect() {
        $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        confirm_db_connect();
        return $connection;
    }

    function db_disconnect($connection) {
        if(isset($connection)) {
            mysqli_close($connection);
        }
    }

    function confirm_db_connect() {
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            $msg = "Database connection failed: ";
            $msg .= mysqli_connect_error();
            $msg .= " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")";
            exit($msg);
        }
    }

    function confirm_result_set($result_set) {
    if (!$result_set) {
        exit("Database query failed.");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [MCVE] please!

Comment: Check and comment if any error you get using my suggestion?

Comment: Thank you, but it still isn't working - and there was no error.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "fetch.php",
data:'state_id='+val,

success: function(data){
 $("#city").html(data);
 }
 });
```

As far as I know the data should be passed like this:

```
data: { 
        'state_id': val
    }
```

Try doing a `echo"TEST";` after `if(isset($_POST['state_id']))` to see if the problem is your jQuery or something else.

Comment: Thanks for the help - tried this too, but didn't work. Eventually I figured it out - I didn't have jquery referenced in the header so ajax wasn't working.